# Create an Incident by web service into Dynamics CRM4

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm-4

I have been literally banging my head on the desk for days on this one.
My create account xml request works fine, but my incident xml request doesnt work.

Here it is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  $accountsRequest = EntityUtils::getCreateCRMSoapHeader($CRMURL, $securityData).
    '
          <s:Body>
                <Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
                <entity xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <b:Attributes xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                        <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <c:key>ownerid</c:key>  
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $ownerid . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>customerid</c:key>  
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $customerid . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>subjectid</c:key>  
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $subjectid . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>title</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $title . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_surveyid</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_survey_id . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_leadsource</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_leadsource . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_forename</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_forename . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_surname</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_surname . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_company</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_company . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_email</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_email . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_phone</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_phone . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_datetravel</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_datetravel . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_drivername</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_drivername . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_punctuality_pickup</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_punctuality_pickup . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_punctuality_dropoff</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_punctuality_dropoff . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_interior</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_interior . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_exterior</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_exterior . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_courtesy</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_courtesy . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_appearance</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_appearance . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_comments</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_comments . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_survey_date</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_survey_date . '</c:value>
                            <c:key>new_survey_score</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $new_survey_score . '</c:value>
                        </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    </b:Attributes>
                    <b:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                    <b:FormattedValues xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                    <b:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:Id>
                    <b:LogicalName>incident</b:LogicalName>
                    <b:RelatedEntities xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                </entity>
                </Create>
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
        ';
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error returned?

Comment: Hi James,  It is encapsulated in PHP and returns no error except for a PHP one saying there is nothing valid returned.   The request above doesn't create anything at the other end but the create account one which is what I based the xml above on works fine.  Obviously there are a number of custom case fields above but they work fine on a fetch xml.  Sorry if that doesn't help.  I am new to CRM and Soap.

Comment: Well you should get a web service response - often they will contain the error. Or you could try enabling tracing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490

Comment: OK, so I got some feedback from the server - Response from server : schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/…: ownerid cannot be set to NULL-2147220989Attribute: ownerid cannot be set to NULL2013-03-11T20:58:26.412378Z-2147220989Attribute: ownerid cannot be set to NULL2013-03-11T20:58:26.412378Z - Any help please would be appreciated

Comment: What are you passing as arguments?

Comment: 6aec51c2-869a-e111-a885-0026558302bbsystemuserJoe Bloggs

Comment: Also tried 6aec51c2-869a-e111-a885-0026558302bb with no luck

Comment: I know this is answered and hoping that you see this; have you figured out how to use the b:RelatedEntities yet? I'm trying to create opportunities and have to associate the account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question - the XML wasn't correctly formed - problems with namespaces mainly. Plus a couple of type issues with CRM Incident fields.  Couldn't have done this without the prompters from above so thanks guys.  XML below for anyone getting stuck in future.

customerid
                                
                                    6caff60a-f77c-e211-b2fb-d48564518ccb
                                    account

```
                        <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>                         
                            <c:key>title</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Its a sunday web case - second</c:value>
                        </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    </b:Attributes>
                    <b:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                    <b:FormattedValues xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                    <b:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:Id>
                    <b:LogicalName>incident</b:LogicalName>
                    <b:RelatedEntities xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                </entity>
        </Create>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i don't find any error, active [trace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490) and see which error crm dynamics is launching. Can be an attribute had a typo error.

Comment: Thanks for looking Pedro.  I have no idea how to setup trace on a multi tenanted server.  My client is the admin and I have no web access.  Is there a web way of getting feedback?

Comment: I have checked some more and can find no way to setup tracing on a multi-tenanted hosted server.   Any other suggestion how to debug please?

Comment: So you can't access to server? You can't ask for activate the trace or check the event viewer? A advice i can give you is reduce the amount of information to create the incident, try send just the standard fields of incident if it's any your custom attribute that is giving error. The user you are using has permissions for that operation?

Comment: Hi, I had stupidly turned off the webservice response.  I have this now.  Apparently, I am trying to send a null ownerid.  I will debug this later.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you are passing null in ownerid? You can do debug, right? You have to pass a GUID

Answer (score 0):

Are these meant to be strings?

```
<c:key>ownerid</c:key>  
<c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $ownerid . '</c:value>
<c:key>customerid</c:key>  
<c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . $customerid . '</c:value>
```

If I was doing this via the CRM SDK I would be using an entity reference.

e.g.

```
Entity e = new Entity("incident");
e["customerid"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactId); //or "account", accountId
e["ownerid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", userId);
service.Create(e);
```

Comment: Yeah, what I've posted is in essence one big string with variables injected.  The code is in PHP and calls some functions from a Microsoft lab that I downloaded.  As I mentioned earlier, the code creates an account no problem and runs fetched fine.  Just doesn't create an incident.  I will double check the entity names that I am using, maybe one of those is incorrect.

Comment: OK So Ive amended my xml as below - Now it's saying I need to specify a parent contact or account but I'm sure I am doing that.

Comment: You get that when the customerid isnt specified so I would have a closer look at that.